# Spring boot restful api + hibernate, How to dynamically change table prefix after intercepting url

Tags: hibernate, dynamic, spring-boot, joomla

I have a joomla website where i can create multiple sites(multi sites), all new sites created with joomla are stored in a single database. Every site has the same tables but has his own prefix for table name.'site_id_tablename' (site1_facilities,  site2_facilities)

I have written a Spring boot RESTful API. This api now only works with 1 site. I have not found a way to switch the table prefix at runtime. I would like to intercept the url visited from a mobile client. 'site.com/api/{site_id}/facilities'

and get the correct data from the table matches site_id;

Example: 'site.com/api/site1/facilities'

I have tried the multi tenant approach described by : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html

This is not working because everything is in a single DB. Unfortunately i am not allowed to make changes to the database.

Is there a way to switch from table prefix at runtime or is there any other solution to solve this problem.

Comment: Please check if this thread helps you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187589/spring-boot-jpa-hibernate-different-table-name-prefix

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot + JPA + Hibernate different table name prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187589/spring-boot-jpa-hibernate-different-table-name-prefix)