# Spring Boot + JPA + Hibernate different table name prefix

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am working on a multi-tenanted application (with old database structure)  where I have a common **user** table and set of tables based on the access permission.

For example if the user can work with invoice of different companies C1 and C2, the database contains a tables with name C1_invoice and C2_invoice.

I am able to achieve adding prefix with one company using **org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl**

So I can access **C1_invoice** table. But how can I choose the prefix C1 or C2 dynamically?

Comment: I believe it's simpler if you use company ids as a foreign key for each invoice records. That way the application will scale without added more and more tables in future, say for C3 and C4.

Comment: Interesting question though.

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan, I believe 'old database structure' implies a legacy schema that cannot be changed

Comment: didn't notice that. Pardon me.

Comment: @RajaAnbazhaganYes it is old schema.Can not change just now.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a variation of [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44135582/how-to-enable-multitenancy-with-spring-data-jpa).

It is basically using hibernate's multitenancy features in Spring Data by providing a custom `MultiTenantConnectionProvider`. The connection provider reads connection details from a map of data sources. You could provide a different value for the `hibernate.physical_naming_strategy` in each of the data sources. I'm not sure if there's a way to specify the prefix for each data source as a property, though. You could end up with a separate subclass of the `PhysicalNamingStrategy` for each tenant. Could be gruesome.

What DB are you using? Alternatively, you could resolve the issue by providing a schema per each tenant, and aliasing their tables from the default schema using unprefixed names, something along the lines of:

```
CREATE SYNONYM C1.INVOICE FOR DEFAULT.C1_INVOICE;
```

This way, you could use Hibernate's standard `MultitenancyStrategy.SCHEMA` strategy.

Comment: Hello, I tried to implement that way. However, I in that approach, I need to specify the data sources in advance. But my problem is different. I need to decide which table to be accessed based on which company is accessed. Is there a way where I can do the query injection in Repository?